# Find the probability that one event or the intersection of two events occur.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given that at least one, but no more than three, of the events $A_r$, $1\le r\le n$, occur, $n\ge3$. The probability of at least two occurring is $\frac{1}{2}$. If $\Bbb P(A_r) = p, \Bbb P(A_r\cap A_s) = q, r \neq s$, and $\Bbb P(A_r\cap A_s\cap A_t)=x, r\lt s\lt t$, show that $p\ge \frac{3}{2n}$, and $q\le \frac{4}{n}$.

I know that $\Bbb P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n \Bbb P(A_i) - \sum_{i<j} \Bbb P(A_i\cap A_j)+...+(-1)^{n+1} \Bbb P(A_1\cap...\cap A_n)$.

Since at least one of the $A_r$ occurs, the solution applies the rule above and get $1=\Bbb P(\bigcup_1^n A_r) = \sum_r \Bbb P(A_r)-\sum_{r<s} \Bbb P(A_r\cap A_s) + \sum_{r \lt s \lt t} \Bbb P(A_r \cap A_s \cap A_t) = np-{n \choose 2}q + {n \choose 3} x.$

The solution proceeds that

> since at least two of the events occur with probability $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} = \Bbb P(\bigcup_{r \lt s}(A_r \cap A_s)) = \sum_{ r \lt s} \Bbb P(A_r \cap A_s) - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{r \lt s, t \lt u, (r,s) \neq (t,u)} \Bbb P(A_r \cap A_s
> \cap A_t \cap A_u)$ + ...
>   By a careful consideration of the first three terms in the latter series, we find that $\frac{1}{2} = {n \choose 2}q - 3{n \choose 3}x + {n \choose 3}x.$

I don't quite understand why there is a coefficient of $\frac{1}{2}$ before the second term of the latter series and how the second term and the third term in the latter series become $- 3{n \choose 3}x + {n \choose 3}x$. Besides, I think the second term in the latter series implies 4 events happen at a time, which seems to contradict with the requirement that at most 3 events happen at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coefficient of $\frac{1}{2}$is just to exclude the case of repetition as $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 $ is the same as $A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_1 \cap A_2 $. For the second term in the latter series, as there are at most 3 events happening at a time, exactly one event appears twice. ${3 \choose 1} = 3$. For the third term, there is only one possibility to have 3 pairs of events from 3 distinct events. In both the second term and the third term, there are in fact three events happening, so we have an $x$ in both terms.